# Create domain classes according to given JSON file

Tags: json, parsing, grails, rendering

I'm new to Grails, and I'm stuck on the basic structure of my web-app

So far I've implemented a Grails app that renders one JSON file to a readable table.

example
Given JSON file below

```
{
"abbreviation": "EXAMPLE",
"guid": "31ac235e2-3ad3-43e3-1fd4-41e6dfwegf03",
"metadata": {
  "dataOrigin": "Example"
},
"rooms": 
[
],
"site": {
  "guid": "31ac235e2-3ad3-43e3-1fd4-41e6dfwegf03"
"title": "Example Testing"
}
}
```

My app renders above JSON file to below

- Abbreviation : Example
- GUID : 31ac235e2-3ad3-43e3-1fd4-41e6dfwegf03
- Metadata : - DataOrigin : Example
- Rooms : []
- Site - GUID : 31ac235e2-3ad3-43e3-1fd4-41e6dfwegf03
- Title : Exmaple Testing

Now, what should I do if I want my app to read JSON files with different Name/value pairs and renders it similarly to what my app does now?
(I've hard coded the application I have now)

I know this question is very vague, but can anyone give me any directions or insights on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid if there was a simply answer to this question then half of the web developers would be out of their jobs :-)

Anyway, there's probably several steps that could help in achieving your goal.

1. JSONSlurper(http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) to read JSON files. Obviously if you go for predefined structures you could use GSON (https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) or similar library.
2. To display arbitrary data you can use the Grails Fields plugin(https://grails.org/plugin/fields).

I know it's all only pointers.

Comment: Thanks! I'll starting researching on suggestions you made :)